# how often should a javascript variable be defined?

Tags: javascript

I've always defined the counter variable using `var` in my JavaScript `for` loops.  I've recently realized that I am defining the same variable twice when I have multiple loops in a given script.  Is there any problem with doing the following, or should I only define `i` once?

```
for (var i = 0; i < var1.length; i++){
    //do something with var1[i]
}
for (var i = 0; i < var2.length; i++){
    //do something with var2[i]
}
```

Comment: Declarations after the first one have no effect.

Comment: @Pointy.  So no problem doing so?  Do you personally include the `var` in each `for` loop?  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything, but I personally try to avoid it just to keep the code cleaner. I also try to use things like `.map` and `.reduce` when possible to skip `for` loops altogether, though that's not always possible/practical.

Comment: I agree with previous comments. But as long as you don't use "i" asynchronously in any of the for loops you'll be fine.

Comment: If you use JSHint it will warn you that you've declared the same variable twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work (although could have unforeseen consequences) because of hoisting. Hoisting means that all declarations in a function are "hoisted" to the top during interpretation (which is fine because JavaScript has function scope anyway). Your code winds up being interpreted as:

```
function() {
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < var1.length; i++) { }
    for(i = 0; i < var1.length; i++) { }
}
```

So you can see that even though you think you declared `i` multiple times, both declarations are hoisted to the top and re-use the same variable.

As long as the two are used independently, you shouldn't technically have any issues. Unfortunately it makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

A variable should only be defined once in its scope, unless available in the lexical scope. For your example, you should be doing:

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < var1.length; i++){
    //...
}
for (i = 0; i < var1.length; i++){
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't prevent changes to that variable however.

If I do:

```
var i = 0;

function A () {
    i = 1;
}
A();
```

This will change `i` to `1`. You're not redefining it, but passing it about and changing its value. This of course is a very simple example.

Answer (score 0):

While declaring & initializing a variable in each for loop may give you a small overhead (with small I mean really small), I don't think that you should switch to declaring only once.

Declaring & initializing the counter variable in every for-loop separately is much more easily to read / handle and far more error-proof (what if you forget to reset the counter variable after a for loop?).

Comment: This we my original thought as well, but it is in conflict with the other answers.

Comment: @user1032531 I am sry, but I don't see any conflict ;)

Comment: You seem to advocate declaring the counter variable in every for-loop separately as it is much more easily to read.  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: "Declaring" and "initializing" are not the same thing, so your statement about "what if you forget to reset the counter" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score -3):

Variables are only contained within the statement. The only time you would have to worry about multiple variables are in either nested statements or re-declaring predeclared variables.

Comment: This is not true in JavaScript.

Comment: How so? The variable is contained inside the loop unless you pre-declare a variable outside the loop (e.g. `var myvar`), and then assign a value to that variable to change it inside the loop.

Comment: @T145 - JavaScript uses Function Scope which means that a variable declared anywhere inside of a function is available everywhere inside the function.

Comment: @T145 JavaScript is not like Java in this regard. The only scope is function scope, and a `var` **anywhere** inside a function is treated as if it appeared at the top of the function body.

Comment: This I know, you're misunderstanding my point. It is exemplified in @Todd Motto's answer.

Comment: Well OK, but your "only contained within the statement" wording is therefore kind-of confusing, as `var` declarations have nothing to do with individual statements.

Comment: Sorry about that. You could've just edited my answer to help improve how everyone perceives it so it wouldn't get downvoted though :P

Comment: If someone edited your answer, then it would totally change the meaning of the answer you actually wrote!  Hence this comment thread. :)